# FetchPlan in orientDB

Tags: java, orientdb

I have an Edge class 'Depends' and i want to load all the fields except those pointed by in_Depends. fetchPlan:*:-1 results in a stack overflow on the orientDB console, probably due to the size of my data.

I am running:

```
SELECT @this.toJSON('fetchPlan:[ * ]in_*:-2 *:8') FROM #11:248836
```

However it also loads the in_Depends fields making the graph heavy. I want to eventually be able to do '**fetchPlan:[ * ]in_*:-2 *:-1**'.

Thanks.

Comment: This syntax with square brackets is not supported. What you want to do with `[ * ]` ?

Comment: @Lvca Thanks for your reply, i am following the documentation where [*] instructs the rule to apply at all levels,  according to http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Fetching-Strategies.html, by the way i am not putting the extra space before and after the star

Comment: @Lvca i have also tried without the square brackets running,                      SELECT @this.toJSON('fetchPlan:in_*:-2 \*:8') FROM #11:248836  . It also loads the nodes pointed by in_Depends. Additionally i tried to increase the stack space to 2m in the JVM but fetching everything still results in a stack overflow. SELECT @this.toJSON('fetchPlan:in_*:-2 *:-1') FROM #11:248836

Comment: What release are you using?

Comment: The latest one - 2.1 rc4 which was just released.